# Как вывести из базы данных MySQL цикл без лимита?

Tags: while, php, mysql

Вот блок:

```
<ul id="tiles">
    <li class="mackay"><img src="/images/image_1.jpg" height="283" width="200">
    <p>London Art</p>
    <div class="discription-block">
        <a href="#" target="blank"><p class="buy-main">view</p></a>
    </div>
 </li>      
</ul>
```

потом

```
<?
$result=mysql_query("SELECT name,image,classfilt FROM mackmybase");
$n=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
```

А теперь надо этот блок вывести в цикле без лимита,
`name` этот будет

```
London Art
```

`image` этот

```
<img src="/images/image_1.jpg" height="283" width="200">
```

(заменить только ссылку),
и

`classfilt` это

```
class="mackay"
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, что такое цикл без лимита?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Переформулируйте пожалуйста ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$result=mysqlquery("SELECT name,image,classfilt FROM mackmybase");
$n=mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo <<< HEREDOC
<ul id="tiles">
<li class="$row[classfilt]"><img src="$row[image]" height="283" width="200">
<p>$row[name]</p>
<div class="discription-block">
    <a href="#" target="blank"><p class="buy-main">view</p></a>
</div>
</li>      
</ul>
HEREDOC;
};

function mysqlquery($query){ // для удобной отладки
    $result= mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) die("Неверный запрос: ".mysql_error()."\n".$query);
    return $result;
};
```

Comment: спасибо, теперь понял что да как. Смотри, вот теперь кирилицу не отображает, на второй картине глянь http://music.mackay.kz/ хотя кодировку utf8 стоит? Почему так, как исправить?

Comment: @Mackay, надо смотреть в какой кодировке база данных, похоже, что не UTF-8

Comment: незнаю, вот на главной странице пишет MySQL-кодировка: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8), может как то можно написать в sql, ток я незнаю как

Comment: В 16-ричном виде с Вашего сайта приходит  

    3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F
что есть просто знаки вопроса, значит проблема с кодировкой на одном из этапов:  
1. Запись в БД  
2. Чтение из БД